# How can an Automation be deleted using ExactTarget SOAP API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs, automationstudio

I have a delete request coded using the SOAP API and the response back is:

> AutomationDelete:["Delete Access is denied!", 0]"Error"

Is the action truly denied or am I not writing the code properly?  Here is the API code:

```
var Automation = Platform.Function.CreateObject("Automation");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Automation, "CustomerKey", "MyAutomation");

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
var DeleteResults = Platform.Function.InvokeDelete(Automation, StatusAndRequestID, null);
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found that it does work, but NOT from a CloudPage (this triggers "Delete Access is Denied!").
Only from within an SSJS Script activity. Here is the WSProxy version of the code.

I used the Object ID which you have to retrieve in advance. See here:
https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-starting-an-automation-with-ssjs/

Not sure if this works with the Customerkey.

```
var automationToDelete = "OBJECT ID OF AN AUTOMATION"; 
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    try {
       var res = prox.deleteItem("Automation", { "ObjectID": automationToDelete
});
   } catch (e) {
    //error processing
   }
```