# Delete Automations through API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, automationstudio

Is it true that you can only create new automations through API, and not deleting them? We have a client, that by mistake made 9000 automations, and now we want to remove them through the API, instead of manuel. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see it listing in the documentation but you **can** delete Automations in the same way you would delete any other object that supports a delete operation assuming you have the correct permission set on your API user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works, but only from SSJS Script activities. See here:

[How can an Automation be deleted using ExactTarget SOAP API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75711/how-can-an-automation-be-deleted-using-exacttarget-soap-api/262131#262131)